# android maven plugin can not find classes from apklib

Tags: android, maven

I have a library : pom.xml http://pastebin.com/BEvR041z
and a sample app: pom.xml http://pastebin.com/bVWESmtf

The project builds sucessful from IDE (without maven) however I decided to write maven build script (see the links above).

The library is compiled and installed successful, but when I try to build sample app I get a dozen of errors

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project android-cluster-sample: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/anatoly/IdeaProjects/android-map-cluster/sample/src/ru/realweb/map/cluster/sample/MainActivity.java:[13,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class ClusterOverlay
[ERROR] location: package ru.realweb.map.cluster
```

ClusterOverlay is a class from library so classes from the library somehow cannot be found found.

So guys, what do you think? What have I done wrong?

UPDATE: The problem is in library pom, because i unzipped the apklib file from local repo and there is no classes at all

Comment: It looks like you haven't added the dependency from one module to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add sources references so the java classes were not copied to the destination apklib.

```
<build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        ...
</build>
```

Comment: That's the problem with using non conventions in Maven usw src/main/java src/test/java etc. instead of something different.